# convert maven jar and copy resources plugin to gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I am new to gradle and trying to convert my POM into gradle.build. I have convert the dependencies part and now converting plugin part. I have following in my POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>
                    junit, org.apache.logging.log4j, org.springframework, aopalliance, org.springframework.data, javax.inject, 
                        org.hibernate, javax.el, com.microsoft.sqlserver, org.apache.commons, com.jcraft, com.sun.mail, 
                        org.apache.velocity, commons-lang, commons-logging, commons-collections, org.jboss.logging, 
                        org.jboss, org.javassist, dom4j, javax.transaction
                </includeGroupIds>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.vm</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries> 
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.vm</include>
                            <include>**/*.txt</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I ran this POM then I got structure like this

[image: Project structure]

[image: dependency-jars folder]

[image: conf folder]

Now I tried it with the following with gradle jar task

```
apply plugin: 'application' // implicitly apply java and distribution plugin
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = sourceCompatibility
mainClassName = "com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport"
version = '1.0'

ext {
    log4jGroupId = "org.apache.logging.log4j"
    springFrameworkGroupId = "org.springframework"
    springFrameworkVersion = "4.2.4.RELEASE"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
    ....
}

dependencies {
    compile group: log4jGroupId, name: 'log4j-api', version: log4jVersion
    ....
    runtime group: 'org.jboss.logging', name: 'jboss-logging', version: jbossLoggingVersion
    ....
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
}

jar {

    // Keep jar clean:
    exclude '**/*.properties', '**/*.xml', '**/*.vm', '**/*.txt'

    //from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest { 
       attributes ('Implementation-Version': version,
           'Main-Class': "$mainClassName",
           'Class-Path': "conf/" + " " + configurations.runtime.files.collect {"dependency-jars/$it.name" }.join(' ')
       )
    }
}
```

Then I got the following jar

[image]

It is generate proper class path in jar. But `build/libs/` folder only contain jar, there is no `dependency-jars` and `conf` folders in it. How can I create these folders, so when i run task jar, it creates jar in `build/libs/` folder, also create `dependency-jars` folder with all jars in it. And `conf` folder in `build/libs`, with all the `.propeties, .xml, .vm, .txt`files from `src/main/resources/` folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hhmm I tried the following and it worked. I don't know how well this approach is. But if someone has better way to do it then please post answer too.

```
....
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}

task copyJars(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/libs/dependency-jars"
}

task copyConfigurationFiles(type: Copy) {
    description 'Copies the configurations files src/main/resources directory (from) to the target directory(into).'
    from "src/main/resources"
    into "$buildDir/libs/conf"
    include '**/*.properties', '**/*.xml', '**/*.vm', '**/*.txt'
}

task copyFiles(dependsOn: [copyJars, copyConfigurationFiles])

jar {

    dependsOn copyFiles

    // Keep jar clean:
    exclude '**/*.properties', '**/*.xml', '**/*.vm', '**/*.txt'

    manifest { 
        attributes ('Implementation-Version': version,
           'Main-Class': "$mainClassName",
           'Class-Path': "conf/" + " " + configurations.runtime.files.collect {"dependency-jars/$it.name" }.join(' ')
       )
    }
}
```

After that I simply run task jar. And it created the jar, as well as dependency-jars folder with all jars in it and also conf folder with all configuration files in it. Just like when I did `maven install`

Thanks